# Returning more than one result mysql & php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello basically I am trying to return the 3 values that are in category_name table.
however this is proving impossible.... When I do the var dump i get `array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "one" ["category_name"]=> string(3) "one" }` and i dont know what i am doing wrong

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","");
mysql_select_db("test",$connection);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT category_name FROM category ");
$result2 = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
var_dump ($result2)
```

Comment: Double-check to be sure that the category table has 3 rows of data. This code should work.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: So you're executing mysql_fetch_array() only once, so it will only fetch one result.... now you know you need to keep calling mysql_fetch_array() to fetch each returned row, move up to MySQLi or PDO

Comment: Inserted them myself manually and also run the select statement in the SQL console and it returns 3 :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a loop, since `mysql_fetch_array()` will only fetch **one** row at a time:

```
$cats = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
    $cats[] = $row;
}

var_dump( $cats); // This will have all three categories in it
```

The above loops `mysql_fetch_array()` until there is no data left, adding the rows returned from the DB into the `$cats` array.

Comment: Nick, i do that and i get `array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "dos" ["category_name"]=> string(3) "dos" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "tres" ["category_name"]=> string(4) "tres" } }`  and i am still missing 1 result

Comment: @Jonathan - Are you sure you copied my post exactly? If so, it looks like you have two rows in the table and nothing else. Make sure you don't call `mysql_fetch_array()` before this loop.

Comment: yup copied it exactly as it is there. its weird :S.. I am looking at the db and it has 3 rows @_@

Answer (score 1):

First - you have to switch to **mysqli** or **PDO**

Second - you have to loop through your returned data. In your current script you're fetching just one result into your array.

```
$connection = mysql_connect( "localhost", "admin", "" );
mysql_select_db( "test", $connection );
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT category_name FROM category" );

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    echo $row['category_name'], "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the first row from your result set.

Subsequent calls to mysql_fetch_array will return the next result row.

Try using:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   var_dump($row);
}
```

The issue with the other answers that appears to be confusing the OP is that `MYSQL_ASSOC` tells mysql_fetch_array to return an array using column names as indexes instead of the default `MYSQL_BOTH` (which uses numeric and named array indexes).

Hope that helps!